# Facebook sdk 3.5.2 on android has a strange behaviour

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I'm developing an application to enable user to share data on Facebook

I have this strange behavior :

Using Nexus one (OS: 2.3.2) it is working very well
Using Samsung Tablet (OS : 4.0) it always return me session with this states (CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED)
Using Samsung (OS : 2.2) it is not calling onActivityResult to return to me the session
Using Sony Xperia (OS : 4.0.1) it always open facebook with some problem in authentication

Comment: My problem is same as this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193614/not-being-able-to-authenticate-using-in-android-app

Comment: See my comment in the other question, please print out the exception that you get back in your callback.